# C# mvc project db.savechanges() not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem concerning the following code snippet for my university project. The system this is implemented in is a library for books - nothing too special as i am new to EF and MVC. The following is the `[Http-Post]` Method of creating a lending. When a lending is created, i want to make sure all reserves concerning the same `User` and the same `Medium` will be marked as `served` so they won't play a role for the next lending.

My problem is, that it won't save the changes the reserve-item. Does anybody see a reason why? It's not the only place i change values, but i'm not able to find out whats different here.

**Model**

```
public partial class Reserve
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ReserveDate { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public bool Served { get; set; }
    public virtual Medium Medium { get; set; }
}
```

**Code**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,LendingDate,ExpiryDate,ReturnDate,User,Copy")] Lending lending, int? Copy_ID)
{
    lending.Copy = db.CopySet.Find(Copy_ID);
    lending.LendingDate = DateTime.Today;
    lending.ExpiryDate = lending.LendingDate.AddDays(DaysToExpiry);
    lending.ReturnDate = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //wenn ausleihe erfolgt, die Reservierung finden, die zu Benutzer und Medium passt
        List<Reserve> resList = db.ReserveSet.Where(x => x.User.Contains(lending.User) && x.Medium.Id.Equals(lending.Copy.Medium.Id)).ToList();

        //für alle Elemente 
        foreach (Reserve r in resList)
        {
            Reserve res =  db.ReserveSet.Find(r.Id);
            res.Served = true;
            db.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        db.LendingSet.Add(lending);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(lending);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? are you sure that ModelState.IsValid is true?

Comment: Your question is unclear... where in this method does the program error out?

Comment: The code runs smoothly (no error msg) - it creates the lending but it doesn't save the changes made to the reserves. So to be clear - it doesn't set "served" to true in the database.

Comment: so then it is not entering the foreach loop?  have you debugged to find out why?  Does your list have any objects inside of it?

Comment: Does resList count is greater than 0 ? Did you try to just save lending? Try using 1 SaveChanges by using linq, instead of foreach loop, like this; `resList.ForEach(x=> x.Server = true);`. Please be more spesific and give more details.

Comment: It enters the foreach and the list has 3 Objects in it. It does even change the served value it to these objects in the list. But then it doesn't carry over to the database.

Comment: it seems to me that there is something that you are missing/not telling us... honestly from my point of view I don't see anything wrong with your code but *only you* can tell us based on the **debugger**.. when you debug.. after this line `db.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;` does `res` get successfully modified?

Comment: [Debug Screen](https://pl.vc/1h12g3) It seems it gets updated. I'm terribly sorry if i can't give you the right answers. I am new to this and have no backround knowlegde concerning ef or asp.net.

Comment: in the pic you uploaded.. your `res.Served = true` is commented out..

Comment: i know, as i did what berkay said above. I tried and it does the same though.

Comment: you are *sure* that the records being stored in that list are what you are expecting?

Comment: Are you use a local database file?  When you build does the file get copied to the output?  If so are you updating the _copy_ and not the original file?

Comment: @fireydude it doesn't work without changing the state eighter

Comment: @DStanley i don't know if i understand you correctly but the database is at my university, so no local database file. Every other changes apply to the database - e.g. in this snippet the lending is created an stored in the database correctly.

Comment: @Mbrzeske Just as a heads up you probably shouldn't be calling db save changes in a loop, you should just call it once at the end.  You will be creating alot of excess communication between you application and your database, and if an error occurs you have partially saved data

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks - i cut it out of the loop. Wasn't sure if it does carry over that way.

Comment: Two pieces of additional Info: 1. I tried to change the Served value to true in the constructor and even that doesn't work. It somehow automatically sets itself to false. 2. The served field was added later in the process to keep querys short - so if nobody knows an answer i will code around it. Thank you guys for the help, this was my first post here and even if we can't solve this, i really appreciate your work,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what will happen when you do this.  Your pulling the entity out from your reserve set twice, which can mess up change tracking.  This code is redundant, you already have the items you need there is not reason to call find if your just setting all of the served to true.  Also your call to save changes is going to cause excess communication between sql and your application, if for some reason one of you items fails to save then you will have partially saved data just call it once at then end instead.

```
List<Reserve> resList = db.ReserveSet.Where(x => x.User.Contains(lending.User) 
    && x.Medium.Id.Equals(lending.Copy.Medium.Id)).ToList();

//für alle Elemente 
foreach (Reserve r in resList)
{
    Reserve res =  db.ReserveSet.Find(r.Id);
    res.Served = true;
    db.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can just do this instead:

```
List<Reserve> resList = db.ReserveSet.Where(x => x.User.Contains(lending.User)
     && x.Medium.Id.Equals(lending.Copy.Medium.Id)).ToList();

foreach(var res in resList)
{
   res.Served = true;
}    

db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm not sure if that will fix you issue but you can start there.

Comment: You are right - i changed it, but it didn't solve the problem. I didn't know if the `EntitiyState.Modified` was necessary. Seems it doesn't work with or without it.

Comment: Can you write down the reserve ids, next time you debug and check them in the database manually, before your run anything after save changes, to make sure there isn't a function else where in the code that is switching it back

Comment: [Reserve IDs](https://pl.vc/1jtv31) [Reserve IDs DB](https://pl.vc/1fsiji) I checked them right after savechanges - i uploaded two screenshots so you can see.

Comment: Try the links in my previous comment

Comment: @Mbrzeske It says they're false in the code is that before or after saving?

Comment: that screenshot was before the second loop, so served on the third element is still set as false. after exiting the loop i can still check the resList and it says served = true for all three elements.

Comment: what does the code say for served after you call save changes, do they switch back all to false?